# Why MRT rendering fails when the shaders run on the primary graphics card?

Tags: directx, direct3d, directx-11, direct3d11

I have a laptop with two graphics cards: the integrated Intel one and an NVidia GeForce 610M card. I use MRT to do some GPGPU tasks using Direct3D 11 (using D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0). I have problems with the blending (the graphics card should support post pixel shader blending), and a really strange behaviour.

If blending is enabled, windows is started having the integrated graphics card choosen as the preferred graphics card and running the rendering on the NVidia everything works as expected.

If blending is enabled, and windows is started having the NVidia graphics card choosen as the preferred graphics card and running the rendering on the Nvidia the graphics driver hangs; the d3d11 debug layer is enabled and working, but I don't get any errors.

If the blending is commented out everything works fine, but I need the blending. I tested these scenarios several times. I had to restart my computer after every change to the preferred graphics card.

My theory is that GeForce M610 is not good enough for handling both windows and my application (Windows uses itself its resources), thats why the program hangs when I use the second scenario; but I suspect this too unstable to be actually correct. How could I write stable applications if the graphics card API says that D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0 is supported, then it hangs? What should I do to prevent this? Am I wrong with my theory?

The hang occurs during the Map call.

```
    D3D11_TEXTURE3D_DESC td = {};
texture->GetDesc(&td);
td.BindFlags = 0;
td.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_STAGING;
td.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_READ;
result.resize(td.Width * td.Height * td.Depth);

CComPtr<ID3D11Texture3D> tex3d;
HRESULT hr = device->CreateTexture3D(&td, nullptr, &tex3d);
if(FAILED(hr))
{
    throw hr;
}

D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE ms = {};
context->CopyResource(tex3d, texture);
```

Comment: On any system that supports feature level 11, the OS virtualizes GPU memory so that if you overcommit, things just get slow, but they shouldn't hang.  Have you tried updating your video drivers?  Also, where does the hang occur?  Is it on Draw? Dispatch?  Also, unless you have explicitly disabled it, a GPU hang should cause a [TDR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff570087(v=vs.85).aspx).  Does that happen or does it just hard hang?

Comment: It occurs during mapping the staging buffer (in which I copied one of the render targets). The copying works when the blending is not enabled. The error is similar to a TDR, but not a TDR. The error message is shown in a bubble saying "Diplay Driver stopped working and has recovered. Display Driver NVIDIA Kernel Mode Driver Version 327.02 stopped responding and has successfully recovered". I think I have the latest driver. I will add a snippet of my code to my original question.

Comment: are you sure the debug layer is enabled?  If the driver is crashing (which is accompanied by the "stopped working" message), you should at least get a debug message along the lines of `D3D11: Removing Device` and then indicate whether it is likely the app's fault or the driver's fault.

Comment: Yes, if I made an error intentionally the error would be shown in the debug window. I also tried to run my code on the reference device, and it worked flawlessy (but very very slowly as expected). My project is pretty complex, but I will assemble a minimal failing code on the weekend, and I will post it here.

Comment: @WebMonster `The hang occurs during the Map call` <- this. Did you checked thousand times that you are not reading/writing beyond buffer boundaries? As always, such bugs lead to undefined behavior and cause strange, hidden errors. Probably Intel and NVIDIA drivers handle this case differently, so Intel doesn't crash (probably a bug in Intel driver). Does "commenting out" blending also changes something else? (mapped buffer size, mapping strategy, anything...)

Comment: @WebMonster Another guess is that you writing to resource as `NO_OVERWRITE` that used by GPU same time: try to unbind it before mapping (for debugging purposes).